# Understanding Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I'm new to Hyperledger Fabric, I'm using the test network to understand and I'm panning to create my own application but I have a couple of questions.

1. Are assets just added manually to the ledger?? Can I add assets using (or calling) an external document or a cloud database?
2. I don't understand how do I add data to the ledger? Also, If I'm going to be dealing with a huge amount of data what should be the correct approach because I cannot add the entire data to the ledger I would only want to add a specific potion of the data, and then use smart contracts. But how would I do that?
3. Does anyone now how to test a chaincode? I'm using the terminal but I don't find it that practical. Are there other ways or platforms to test chaincodes??
4. Does anyone one any support groups or communities in which I can ask questions about Hyperledger Fabric?

I really don't know how I can add assets from a file or an external source, like a JSON or other document, there is not much information out there. Or should I add assets one by one?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

All the bussiness logic must be present in the smart-contract (Chaincode).
You will need an application that connects to the Fabric Network and performs the operations against the smart-contract (like reading and writing data).

You can refer this [sample chaincode](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/main/asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go). And [here is a client application](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/asset-transfer-basic/application-go/assetTransfer.go) that connect with fabric network to execute transactions